# VBA - Collate non empty cell values to a new column

Tags: excel, vba

I have a project on VBA where i want to collate some non empty value of a row to the very last column of the same row, and i have to group those values in a subset.
Maybe, the statement could be misleading, hence i am attaching a screenprint of the problem statement as well.

**Initial Data**

[image: Initial Data]

**Final Data**

[image: Final Data]

**I Could even work with the below output**

[image]

Here is the code that i have tried so far :

```
Sub project()
Dim ConcatItNoDuplicities As String
Dim cellsToConcat As Range
    ConcatItNoDuplicities = ""
    If cellsToConcat Is Nothing Then Exit Sub
    Dim oneCell As Range
    Dim result As String
    For Each oneCell In cellsToConcat.Cells
        Dim cellValue As String
        cellValue = Trim(oneCell.Value)
        If cellValue <> "" Then
            If InStr(1, result, cellValue, vbTextCompare) = 0 Then result = result & cellValue & vbCrLf
        End If
    Next oneCell
    If Len(result) > 0 Then result = Left(result, Len(result) - 1)
    ConcatItNoDuplicities = result
End Sub
```

Somehow this is not working as well.

**EDIT** : With help i could place vbCrLf.

Still need help to obtain desired output.

Let me know if any other details can be provided in the same?

Answer (score 1):

It would be just `If InStr(1, result, cellValue, vbTextCompare) = 0 Then result = result & cellValue & vbCrLf`

Comment: not working actually.. :( anything i am doing wrong?

Comment: Depends by what you mean "not working".  Your code works by contaminating non-empty cells in the way you have specified.  It certainly does not work in the way you described your problem but you have only asked about the use of `vbCrLf` and not the logic of your code.  Perhaps you should rethink and rephrase your question.

Answer (score 1):

If i understood your question i have tried this code and works...

**first i start with this data into sheet**
[image]

**execute the vba code and after i get**
[image]

this is the code that i have tried:

```
Sub test()

Dim item As String

'search fruit:
item = "fruit:"
Call myControl(item, 6) '6 start from column F

'search vegetable:
item = "vegetable:"
Call myControl(item, 7) '7 start from column G

'search grains:
item = "grains:"
Call myControl(item, 8) '8 start from column H

End Sub

Function myControl(ByVal searchItem As String, startColumn)

Dim numColumns, numRows, colStart, endCol, i, c As Long
Dim allTogether As String

allTogether = "" 'this variable will contain all the items ex. fruit or vegetable or grains

'how many columns there are...
numColumns = Cells(1, Columns.count).End(xlToLeft).Column

'how many rows there are...
numRows = Cells(rows.count, "A").End(xlUp).Row

'start from column (the first time is column F after first control start from Column G and so on..)
'colStart = startColumns
endCol = 0

'control how many searchItem there are in the columns
For i = startColumn To numColumns

    If (InStr(Cells(1, i), searchItem) <> 0) Then

        endCol = i

    Else
        i = numColumns + 1
    End If
Next i

If endCol <> 0 Then

    For i = 2 To numRows

        For c = startColumn To endCol

            If (Cells(i, c) <> "") Then

                allTogether = allTogether & " " & Cells(i, c)

            End If
        Next c
        Cells(i, startColumn) = allTogether 'get the element all together (ex. fruit)
        allTogether = ""
    Next i

'delete the columns that i have ragruppated
Range(Cells(1, startColumn + 1), Cells(numRows, endCol)).Delete shift:=xlToLeft
End If

End Function
```

Hope this helps

EDIT POST after your comment.
You can use the inputBox...
update the macro in this way:

```
Sub test()

Dim item As String
Dim col As Long

'search fruit:
item = InputBox("Insert the item") ' example fruit: or vegetable: and so on...

col=InputBox("Insert the column number where you want to start") '6 start from column F
Call myControl(item, col) 

End Sub
```

Insert the column number where you want to start
if you want more input control you have to analyze  input for example if the first input is fruit:, vegetable: and so on... isNumeric the second input...

Comment: Helped a lot actually, though when i ran the results at my data then it gave me a problem. Say, if i had load more columns.. and i have columns as fruit:banana, fruit:apple, fruit:grape, veggie:tomato, veggie:potato, fruit:pineapple, veggie:carrote, ... and so on.. so this macro will skip processing after veggie:potato and will return all the further columns as is. I may try further in this, if you have any insights then do let me know. :)

Comment: yes, you can use input box 2 time...
1) input the name items to search example (fruit: or vegetable: and so on...)
2) number of column where you want to begin
3)you put these input into function as parameters example : Call myControl(input1, input2).
In this situation you can delete the other two call at the function myControl...
keep me update

Answer (score 1):

The following code creates new worksheet for output, defines headers and transforms data:

```
Sub Transform()

    Dim wksOutput As Worksheet
    Dim wksSource As Worksheet
    Dim dic, dic2, r, c, x, key, arr, last_col

    Set dic = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
    Set dic2 = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
    Set wksSource = Sheets("source")
    '// Create output worksheet
    Set wksOutput = Sheets.Add(After:=Sheets(Sheets.Count))

    With wksSource

        '// Get headers
        last_col = .Range("A1").End(xlToRight).Column
        For c = 6 To last_col
            dic(Split(.Cells(1, c), ":")(0) & ":") = 1 '//Don't care the value
        Next

        '// Copy data that doesn't change (columns A:E)
        .Range("A1").CurrentRegion.Resize(, 5).Copy wksOutput.Cells(1)
        '// Output headers
        For Each key In dic.Keys()
            x = x + 1
            wksOutput.Cells(1, 5 + x).Value = key
        Next

        For r = 2 To .Cells(.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
            dic2.RemoveAll
            '// Process each row
            For c = 6 To last_col
                x = .Cells(r, c)
                If Len(x) > 0 Then
                    '// Split value and assign concatenated
                    '// value back to dictionary
                    arr = Split(x, ":")
                    dic2(arr(0)) = dic2(arr(0)) & IIf(dic2.Count > 0, Chr(10), "") & arr(0) & ":" & arr(1)
                End If
            Next
            '// Get dictionary key which is header,
            '// find column by this header and assign value to cell.
            For Each key In dic2.Keys()
                wksOutput.Cells(r, wksOutput.Rows(1).Find(key).Column) = dic2(key)
            Next
        Next

    End With

End Sub
```

[Sample workbook](https://1drv.ms/x/s!AvqfUD6Rp0UCkzDEHGnk4xaRFQjT)

Comment: An issue is that i am getting run time error 91 with object to be defined. I was sure  that objects were defined in the above code. Can you point out what i may be missing here?

Comment: @desmond.carros You can download sample workbook (the link is below the code) and see working example. Let me know if *my* workbook doesn't work for you.